# How do I save a matrix to a file?

Tags: r, file, matrix, dfm

I'm new to code on R. I've got a big document feature matrix(11mln*500000) which I need to save somehow to file which can be later read using not R. Trying to do this:

```
data<-readRDS("dfm")
new_data<-head(data, 11156133, 517888)
df<-as.data.frame(new_data)
write.csv(df, "dfm.csv")
```

But get an error:

```
Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Please help

Comment: If you can't save the entire thing in one go, save it by let's say 1000 lines each time (append to file).

Answer (score 1):

Install and load the `data.table` package, and try the `fwrite` function.